# WPF: Drag/Drop to re-order grid and jiggle

Tags: wpf, animation, drag-and-drop

I need to implement a grid in WPF which has squares that can be dragged/dropped to be re-ordered, but I'm not sure the best way to do it. I was thinking using an ObservableCollection of squares and a UniFormGrid but although I have experience with both WPF and drag/drop, ideally I'd like to do a kind of 'jiggle' when before the user releases the mouse. Any suggestions on a good starting point?

Answer (score 2):

I also ran across these, they might be helpful, though I'm not sure about the "make space for dragged item" behavior.
http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/
which was originally on codeplex, here's part 1: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/gong-wpf-dragdrop.aspx part 2: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/gong-wpf-dragdrop-ii.aspx

I would like to know as well. (I'm looking to duplicate the behavior of tabs in chrome or safari). In searching for answers online I ran across your post.